# No Audio In VSDC editor

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I finished recording a multi audio track recording on obs, and it has no sound (in the editor, as a video its fine.) I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Before Play the recorded track, you may click on "Renders" on down left to let you hear the Audio. Many video software need to click on "Render" or "Enter" before click on "Play" button to hear audio. I hope this may work for you,  thank you.

See: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/380841-VSDC-Free-Video-Capture-No-sound-while-recording

If not, that might be your software encountered problem... you may search for solution or troubleshoot or issue-fixed, for example: [Youtube-VSDC Video Editor: Trouble Shooting Audio Conversion Problems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HCGsdZaz40)

Comment: See: [MUTE OR REPLACE AUDIO IN VSDC FREE VIDEO EDITOR](https://www.excusemytech.com/2019/01/mute-or-replace-audio-in-vsdc-free.html)